# Trouble with scraping data in PHP

Tags: php, dom, web-scraping

I am scrapping data from a website that source code is

```
view-source:http://www.pakdukaan.com/75-computer-cases
```

The code I am using to scrape data is this

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.pakdukaan.com/75-computer-cases'); 

$pk_doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); 

if(!empty($html)){ 
$pk_doc->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors(); 
$pk_xpath = new DOMXPath($pk_doc);
$pk_list = array();
$pk_and_price = $pk_xpath->query('//div[@class="product_list list row "]');

if($pk_and_price->length > 0){  

foreach($pk_and_price as $pat){   
  $name = $pk_xpath->query('//h5[@class="name"]', $pat)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $pkmn_types = array(); 
    $price = $pk_xpath->query('//span[@class="price product-price"]', $pat)

    foreach($types as $type){
        $pkmn_types[] = $type->nodeValue; 
    }
    $pk_list[] = array('name' => $name, 'price' => $pkmn_price);

}
}
}

//output what we have
echo "<pre>";
echo print_r($pk_list);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

But instead of getting all cases names, I am getting just one and other thing is I am getting all the prices of the cases twice times.

This is the output

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => 

                Thermaltake V2 Plus + 350W Power Supply


        [price] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
                        Rs.  4,099                      
                [1] => 
                        Rs.  4,099                      
                [2] => 
                        Rs.  5,899                      
                [3] => 
                        Rs.  5,899                      
                [4] => 
                        Rs.  8,499                      
                [5] => 
                        Rs.  8,499                      
                [6] => 
                        Rs.  9,499                      
                [7] => 
                        Rs.  9,499                      
                [8] => 
                        Rs.  10,350                     
                [9] => 
                        Rs.  10,350                     
                [10] => 
                        Rs.  12,999                     
                [11] => 
                        Rs.  12,999                     
                [12] => 
                        Rs.  17,799                     
                [13] => 
                        Rs.  17,799                     
                [14] => 
                        Rs.  16,199                     
                [15] => 
                        Rs.  16,199                     
                [16] => 
                        Rs.  17,299                     
                [17] => 
                        Rs.  17,299                     
                [18] => 
                        Rs.  16,500                     
                [19] => 
                        Rs.  16,500                     
                [20] => 
                        Rs.  5,899                      
                [21] => 
                        Rs.  5,899                      
                [22] => 
                        Rs.  8,399                      
                [23] => 
                        Rs.  8,399                      
                [24] => 
                        Rs.  4,999                      
                [25] => 
                        Rs.  4,999                      
                [26] => 
                        Rs.  7,599                      
                [27] => 
                        Rs.  7,599                      
                [28] => 
                        Rs.  9,999                      
                [29] => 
                        Rs.  9,999                      
           )
    )
)
1
```

Can anyone help out the problem? I have tried a lot to change the div's classes in source code of website but couldn't get appropriate result.

Comment: Check your html structure once again.

Answer (score 0):

So, let's check your errors:

**First**: you query `$pk_xpath->query('//h5[@class="name"]', $pat)` and then take only `item(0)`.

This means that you **skip** all other `DOMNodes` in xpath-query. But if you do this:

```
$names = $pk_xpath->query('//h5[@class="name"]', $pat);
foreach ($names as $n) {
    echo $n->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You will see **all** names from your page.

**Second**: prices. If you check html of a scraped page you will see that `span[@class="price product-price"]` **doubles** for every item. One `span` is visible and second one is for popup block, currently hidden.

So, you need another xpath query, for example you can find all `.product-meta` items and then search for `price product-price` in them.

Comment: I am just new to this scraping! Can you tell me how to do this finding method?